# System reset BMC of a DSC6005 / C6105

Tags: dell, bmc

I have a Dell DSC6005/<strike>C6105</strike> server (it says DSC6005 in the firmware, <strike>but [according to the internet](http://www.heathreynolds.com/2014/07/homelab-build-dell-dsc6005-6105-freenas.html) it's actually called C6105</strike>).  **EDIT**: The DCS6005 is an unofficial OEM that uses the same chassis as the C6100.

One of the nodes had trouble with its IPMI interface, so I attempted to [reset it](https://serverfault.com/a/223252/192847).  That was clearly a wrong move, because the IPMI interface came in a boot loop.  When I am pinging it, I observe it answering 62 times, then going down for about 46 seconds and the story repeats itself.

Remote `ipmitool` commands time out with `Error: Unable to establish LAN session` and the BIOS reports `BMC: Not working`.  Luckily it doesn't stop the node from booting, it just takes a couple of minutes more.  Taking out the power and removing the CMOS-battery do not change this.

According to the [Dell support forums](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/956/t/19589359), one can attempt a **System reset**, which at this point is the only way out I can think of, apart from replacing the node.  But from this thread I don't understand which jumper I need to set. My hardware matches the photo in that thread, not the drawing.  From what I understand, this should be some jumper, but I simply can't find it.  My searches to documentation for this board also came up short.

Comment: What about a good ole power cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the guy with the photo is asking if it's the 9 pins with a blue base in the top left next to the SATA ports (which I think is a 9-pin USB header, explaining why there's no jumpers on them), and the Dell guy is saying it's to the right of the "empty one" (I assume the 9 pin header), but the photo is too blurry for me to make out what's to the right of it.  It looks like the next thing to the right is some sort of socket, then the thing to the right of that socket might be the jumpers?

Comment: I've had the chance to open the machine another time. It seems like my machine doesn't exactly match the machine in the picture, 9-pin and USB-port are swapped, and two extra pins for the fan. The only pins to the right of it are the clearly visible pins north from the Molex connector.